# How do I integrate AWS AppSync with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, aws-amplify

I need to integrate AWS AppSync with Xamarin Forms?  Is there any Samples?

Comment: Doesnt look likely from this issue https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/901

Comment: That was a while back.  They have made a lot of updates since then.

Comment: Last comment was 28 days ago and the last comment saying “no progress” was 2 months ago.